# Override the NSObject data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

i have one array this array contain Question Objects so here i need to change the positions for array

```
Question *que=[[Question alloc]init];

que=[myarray objectAtIndex:1];

Question *que1=[[Question alloc]init];
que1=[myarray objectAtIndex:2];

here i need to inter change objects each other some 

[que1 setValue: que.name forKey:@"Name"];

[myarray relplaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject:que1];
```

is it right way to set value same objectValues

Please guide me hoe can inter change value.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Does this not work for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are significant issues with your code here:

1. This statement:

   ```
   Question *que = [[Question alloc] init];
   ```

   Allocates a new `Question` instance and assigns it to the variable `que`. When you do:

   ```
   que = [myarray objectAtIndex:1];
   ```

   You are overwriting the `Question` instance that you just allocated, effectively leaking memory (because you never released it). This won't be a problem if you are using ARC but nevertheless it is something to be mindful of because with or without ARC it is pointless. You did this twice, once for `que` and once for `que1`. Since you don't actually need to allocate and initialise a new `Question` instance, you can just do:

   ```
   Question *que = [myarray objectAtIndex:1];
   ```
2. You obtain a reference to a `Question` object and assign it to `que1`. Then you mutate it and want to put it *back into* the array. This is pointless because the array already holds a reference to the same `Question` instance that you obtained with `objectAtIndex:`.
3. You haven't really explained what you are trying to do. Your entire code basically boils down to:

   ```
   [[[myarray objectAtIndex:2] setValue:[[myarray objectAtIndex:1] name] forKey:@"Name"];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work how you intend with what you have shown. Just a few points to be aware of:

1. You need `myarray` to be an `NSMutableArray`
2. You have a typo here: `relplaceObjectAtIndex:2` it should be `replaceObjectAtIndex`
3. Arrays start at index 0, which I'm sure you are aware of.

Comment: thanks for your response myarray contain NSMutable array but i need to interchange objects is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

First use NSMutableArray object to hold it not NSArray

then.

you need to understand one main thing you are holding only a pointer to an object. array is managing it. You have created an object before accessing object inside array, dont do that it creates memory leak. You have to access the object from array only.

```
Question * que1=[myarray objectAtIndex:1];
[que1 retain];
[myarray removeObjectAtIndex:1];

Question * que2=[myarray objectAtIndex:2];
[que2 retain];
[myarray removeObjectAtIndex:2];
```

its possible you are not using ARC and your array is the only owner of the object. So If you remove object from array the it might release the whole object

```
[myarray insertObject:que2 atIndex:1];
[myarray insertObject:que1 atIndex:2];
```

this is a sample to put object in any position.
Read class references [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)